# git merge a file with previous commit

Tags: git, merge

I am a git newbie, sorry if this is a absolute beginner question. Is there a way to merge a file with a previous commit.

What I want to achieve with this is, I have a settings file which keep, well, settings. When I branched out, I changed for example db settings, in order to be able to try out things. Now I merged that branch with master. Now I don't want to checkout previous version of settings file because, I made some adjustments to it which is require by new feature. So I want to merge a file with previous commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's get some terminology straight first.  When you merged your branch back into `master`, your settings file got merged as well, combining the changes you made in the branch with any other changes made in `master` after you branched off.  If I understand correctly, you want to undo some of the changes you made while in the branch, but not all of them.  In git parlance, this is called *reverting* the change.

To do this, use `git log` to find the commit that introduced the changes you want to revert.  If nothing else changed in that commit other than what you want to remove, all you need to do is run `git revert <commit>` and you're good.  This is the main reason why I always put any debug code I know I will want to remove later in its own commit.

If it's not the only change in the commit, all is not lost, but it's a little more complicated.  Run:

```
git revert --no-commit <commit>
git reset HEAD
git add --patch
git commit
git reset --hard
```

The first two commands undo all your changes from the given commit, but don't commit the undos yet.  The `--patch` option to `git add` lets you interactively choose which changes to keep one by one.  Then you commit the changes and `git reset` gets rid of the changes you didn't want to keep.

This answer is assuming the change is a one-time deal.  Use one of the other answers if you want to always keep a different settings file locally than gets pushed to the server.

Answer (score 0):

when you merge your new features should not be removed from the file. if you want the old db settings back, checkout the version of the file before the merge (`HEAD^` just after merge) and amend your last commit. if your new features were added in the branch you have to change db settings back manually.

to avoid such problems in the future, create a template file (`settings.template`) which is tracked by git and contains empty settings. put your real settings file into `.gitignore` and copy the template to the real name, then edit it.

Answer (score -1):

There are 3 scenarios where you need different db settings:

1. Different dev using the same branch
2. Different env using the same branch (ie, QA, staging or production)
3. Same dev using different branches to hit separate environments.

I would take a look at:
1. Having a separate config for just the connection string, if possible
2. Using smudge/clean scripts to transform the settings file that would work on that env
3. Manage merging by using git attributes to explicitly fail on any config changes. A way to do that is to tell git to treat the config file as a binary file.

Have a read about `git attributes` and `git smudge/clean scripts`.